# python find FAILED numbers in log file

Tags: python, windows, robocopy

I would like Python code to search for FAILED number from a file.txt .like here 5 ,  i need to search the FAILED number, whether 0 or any number. then i can send an email the number of failures. 
  I have tried the grep  but it does not works.

```
searchfile = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    if "FAILED" in line: print line
searchfile.close()


             Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :      2575         0      2575         0         5         0
Files :      6039         0      6039         0         0         0
Bytes :   1.547 g         0   1.547 g         0         0         0
Times :   0:00:53   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:53


    Ended : Tue Aug 30 04:32:48 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position of the FAILED column and look at the values at that position in the rows of interest:

```
result = {}
col = 'FAILED'
col_index = None
row_names = {'Dirs', 'Files'}

for l in open('file.txt').readlines():
    if col_index is None:
        if col in l:
            col_index = l.find(col)
    else:
        l_split = l.split()
        if len(l_split) > 0 and l_split[0] in row_names:
            result[l_split[0]] = int(l[col_index:col_index+len(col)])
print(result)
```

Comment: Mikael, if you some time, please tell me the logic of the code above. its working great.

Comment: i wanted to understand where you are storing the values of 'Dirs' and 'Files'

Comment: The values are read and stored in this line `result[l.split()[0]] = int(l[col_index:col_index+len(col)])`. It reads the characters in the "FAILED" column that starts at `col_index` and ends at `col_index+len(col)`.